# How can i remove a buttons image when clicked and change the image to a different one

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button with a custom image on it. 
When i click it, it will change for example play/pause for music.
Right now when i click on the pause button the image changes to "Play.png" image, however the "Pause.png" is behind the new image.

How can i set it to null after being clicked?

Thanks!

*Edited* This is in WPF.

```
        bool isPaused = false;

        if (mediaPlayer.Source != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.Pause();
            isPaused = true;
            if (isPaused)
            {
                btnPause.Content = null;
                btnPause.Content = new Image
                {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/UI Icons/play.png", UriKind.Relative))
                };
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You *replaced* the shown image to `Play.png` when the button clicked and the file is not paused, but you *did not* returned to the normal picture after the button clicked again. Here's the fix:

```
    bool isPaused = false;

    if (mediaPlayer.Source != null)
    {
        if (isPaused)
        {
            mediaPlayer.Pause();
            isPaused = true;
            // I removed the 'btnPause.Content = null;' because it's not needed
            btnPause.Content = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/UI Icons/play.png", UriKind.Relative))
            };
         }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.Play();
            isPaused = false;
            btnPause.Content = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/UI Icons/pause.png", UriKind.Relative))
            };
         }
      }
```